# why while reading a file we always check for -1?

Tags: java, file, unicode, filereader

I am trying to read the file from "read.txt"and while reading a file we always check for -1 (line:while(readfile!=-1).

Why we always check  the end file by  comparing it with **"-1"**.Is there any specific reason?

(int readfile = filereadrer.read();)always returns unicode value by this argument does -1 means the unicode value of end of file,if it is then how we got to know that unicode value of end of file is "-1"

```
public class FilesPractise {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     File file = new File("read.txt");

     file.createNewFile();

     FileReader filereadrer = new FileReader(file);

     int readfile = filereadrer.read();

       while(readfile!=-1){
            System.out.println((char)readfile);

             readfile = filereadrer.read();
    }



}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why we always check the end file by comparing it with "-1".Is there any specific reason?

Because if you don't you will never detect end of stream and you will loop endlessly.

> `(int readfile = filereadrer.read();)` always returns unicode value

No it doesn't. It returns -1 *or* a Unicode value. See the Javadoc.

> by this argument

This is not an argument. It is a false assumption.

> does -1 means the unicode value of end of file

There is no such thing as (a) a Unicode value of -1 or (b) a Unicode value of end of file.

> if it is

It isn't.

> then how we got to know that unicode value of end of file is "-1"

It isn't either -1 or `"-1"`. It is a sentinel value returned by the API *instead* of a Unicode value.

Comment: Just one clarification how you got to know 104 103 10 as: ASCII letter h (U+0068) followed by a Windows-style line break (U+000D U+000A).

Comment: Because 13 is CR and 10 is LF, in any ASCII table you can find. I didn't say anything about the 104.

Answer (score 3):

These things can be found out in the documentation of the methods. For example, the method that you are trying to find out about is `read`, from `FileReader`.

Here is the documentation for the `read` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read--

In the page, under the "Returns" section,

> The character read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

See? That's how you get to know these things.

Comment: ,is there any proof that end of file has unicode of -1

Comment: @sainathpawar I don't think there are negative values in unicode. The unicode character END OF TEXT is U+0003. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0003/index.htm

Comment: yes you are right @sweeper that there are no negative values in unicode.but when I try to print the "System.out.println((char)readfile);",without type casting to char (System.out.println(readfile);)I am getting output as:104
13
10

Comment: So what's your? @sainathpawar

Comment: does this "13"here represents end of file(U+0003)

Comment: No, as I said if it is the end of file, it would print -1 @sainathpawar

Comment: @sainathpawar You don't need a proof of any such thing. `read()` returns -1 *or* a character value from the file. A `char` is unsigned, so the return value of -1 is unambiguously end of file. It is a 'sentinel' value, which cannot possibly occur in the data. The output of `13 10` is a carriage return followed by a line feed.

Comment: When printing the characters using `int`, `104 13 10` is the ASCII letter `h` (U+0068) followed by a Windows-style line break (U+000D U+000A). `read()` returns -1 on EOF because that is what the Java specs guarantee is returned, it has nothing to do with Unicode.

Comment: Just one clarification how you got to know 104 103 10 as: ASCII letter h (U+0068) followed by a Windows-style line break (U+000D U+000A).@EJP

Comment: Because 13 is CR and 10 is LF, in any ASCII table you can find. I didn't say anything about the 104.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,I appreciate the help@EJP

Comment: Just as 13 and 10 are in the ASCII table (carriage return and line feed, respectively), 104 in also in the ASCII table, as the letter `h`